# Prevent float wrapping without specifying width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `float: right` element that wraps underneath the element to its left when width of browser is narrowed. I would like for the element on left to start wrapping its text instead, so that both elements stay on the same row.

To reproduce the problem please look at the jsfiddle example below.  As you size down the output window width you will see the purchase amount wrap below the box.

https://jsfiddle.net/noyabronok/Luqj9xyv/

I pure css solution is preferred.

Comment: Why is not specifying width a requirement?

Comment: I'd like to be able to support any browser window without cutting off text or new scrolling.  If you can suggest the use of width specification such that the element on the left wraps text instead of float right element wrapping down then, by all means, width can be specified as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution without using flex:

https://jsfiddle.net/Luqj9xyv/15/

Mimics a table without actually using a table. I made a change with the HTML to get rid of the `ul` which I felt was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using flexbox...why not use it throughout?

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/noyabronok/Luqj9xyv/13/)

```css
#main {
  max-width: 369px;
  border-style: solid;
}
h4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.primary {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#myicon {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  min-width: 12px;
  background: green;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 22.8px;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  line-height: 22.8px;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.pull-right {} .primary {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 22.8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#units {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 15.7px margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h4>Pay with</h4>
  <div class="primary">
    <ul>
      <li><span id="myicon">&nbsp;</span>
      </li>
      <li class="second">Bow Wow Stuff
        <br>You are now a part of our team!!</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="pull-right">£24.89
      <br>
      <label id="units">GBP</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very good option, but I just learned that flex is not compatible with older browsers.  Shabai's answer with `table-cell` works with IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you were already using flex box...

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <h4>Pay with</h4>
    <div class="primary">
        <span id="myicon">&nbsp;</span>
        <div class="second"> Bow Wow Stuff<br> You are now a part of our team!!
        </div>
        <div>
          £24.89<br>
          <label id="units">GBP</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
  max-width: 369px;
  border-style: solid;
}
h4 {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#myicon {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  min-width: 12px;
  background: green;
}

.primary {
  display:flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#units {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 22px;
}
```